# as3 date should increase itself

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, date, datetime, auto-update

I have figured out that once I set my AS3 date to server datetime, it remains the same for the whole life of it.

It was suppose to be updating itself e.g.

```
I set: 
2012/10/23 5:20
```

and after 2 hour(keep running SWF) it should be

```
2012/10/23 7:20
```

but it remains:

```
2012/10/23 5:20
```

Which is against my requirement, I am searching for a good solution to keep my server time up to date without any interference of client timestamps

Comment: Post some code, your problem is not very clear.

Comment: var clock:Date = new Date("2012/10/23 5:20");

    var tim:Timer = new Timer(1000);
    tim.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,function(){
    // below line behave as constant value every second
        trace(clock.getSeconds());
    });

Comment: Guys really appreciate your help, but still stucked: using @Florent code I tested the clip. When I open it on another computer and changed the machine time, server time loses because difference is calculated between the server and client time which is not right.

Comment: Client time should remain client side! Never trust the client about a timestamp. My code does what it has to: keep server synchronized on the client. If you need to share this information among multiple clients, you have request the server again.

Comment: Client side is messing the server time using your example. Instead I have come up with another solution which keep the state of server time in flash and update it without calling server again for further synching.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks @Florent, @Sohel Khalifa, I have finally resolved the problem. I tried this:

```
var clock:Date = new Date('2012/10/23 5:20:00');
var tim:Timer = new Timer(1000);

tim.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,function(){
    clock.time = clock.time + 1000;
    trace(clock.getMinutes()+":"+clock.getSeconds());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing you need to learn about `Date Class` is that it stores the time details of the moment you create that instance. 
If you create a `Date instance` and try to retrieve the data 5 minutes later, you will get time details at the time you created that instance and not the time you access the property.

In order to constant time updates you will need to use a recurring event such as `ENTER_FRAME` or a `Timer Class` to have your date instance updates constantly.

Following sample uses `Timer Class` :

```
var my_date:Date; 

var my_timer:Timer=new Timer(1000);
my_timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
my_timer.start(); 

function onTimer(e:TimerEvent):void {
my_date = new Date();
trace(my_date.hours + ":" + my_date.minutes + ":" + my_date.seconds);
}
```

Comment: I was also thinking same but it has its own problem. New date will give me client system date, which is not what i need. I will have to keep updating my clock which is at most synched with server time once its get loaded.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to keep the date synchronized is to rely on two dates!

```
public class SyncDate
{
    public function SyncDate(serverDate:Date)
    {
        _localDate = new Date();
        _serverDate = serverDate;
    }

    private var _localDate:Date;
    private var _serverDate:Date;

    public function get date():Date
    {
        var timeDiff:Number = (new Date()).time - _localDate.time;
        return new Date(_serverDate.time + timeDiff);
    }
}
```

When you will call `SyncDate#date` you will get the adjusted server date.

Comment: Thanks, I can call it every second. Great